# Is the polar decomposition useful in the real case as well?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm reading Roman's *Advanced Linear Algebra* p.252, where he talks about the Polar Decomposition. He states the theorem only for the case of $V$ a *complex* inner product space. Wikipedia also states the polar decomposition specifically for complex matrices. Since it works over a real inner product space as well (I believe), why do they emphasize the complex case? Is it merely for generality? Is there a reason why the polar decomposition is less useful (or simpler) over a real inner product space? To me it seems the only difference is that the unitary matrix is now an orthogonal matrix.

Comment: You are correct that there are always polar decompositions over the reals. I don't know why Roman only mentions the theorem over the complex field.